# Does every process has its own page directory?

Tags: operating-system, paging, xv6, pintos

I know that each process has its own page table for VPN to PPN mapping. But do they have separate page directory also?

Comment: They couldn't have different page tables if they would share the same page directory.

Comment: @tkausl If the page tables aren't organized as a tree or if address space switching changes the tree not at the root, they may have the same page directory.